# Google Cloud Vertex AI Endpoint deployment is extremely slow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have built a model using Google Cloud Vertex AI and uploaded to Model Registry. I then try to create an Endpoint with it but I found that it is extremely slow - takes more than 30-40mins. And sometimes it just stick as deploying... Is this normal? Is there any way to speed this up? Or at least is there anywhere I can see any possible error?

Comment: Having the same issue, will like to know if you managed to figure out why

Comment: Even I am facing same problem.

Comment: I am wondering about this too.